# A warning "'init()' is deprecated". [Swift, Ios app, learning model]

Tags: swift, ios-app-extension

I am making a image classification iOS app with Swift.

When I write

```
guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: SqueezeNet().model) else { return }
```

I got this warning.

```
'init()' is deprecated: Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately.
```

Do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You should use `SqueezeNet(configuration:)` instead of `SqueezeNet()`.

Answer (score 7):

As the message notes, `init()` is deprecated. The new initializer takes a configuration parameter. The default configuration may be fine for you, in which case you would replace `SqueezeNet()` with:

```
SqueezeNet(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
```

Answer (score 7):

For me the code of an Apple sample project worked out:

```
guard let mlModel = try? YOLOv3(configuration: .init()).model,
              let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: mlModel) else {
            print("Failed to load detector!")
            return
```

---

---

this was the code which gave me the warning:

```
guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: YOLOv3().model) else {
            print("Could not load model")
            return
```

Answer (score 2):

That's odd. Right click `SqueezeNet()` and jump to it's definition. It will take you to the class.

Find the `init()` method of the class. It should look like this within your `SqueezeNet` class:

```swift
/**
    Construct SqueezeNet instance by automatically loading the model from the app's bundle.
*/
@available(*, deprecated, message: "Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately.")
convenience init() {
    try! self.init(contentsOf: type(of:self).urlOfModelInThisBundle)
}
```

---

I'm not sure how you set up your ML, but it appears as though the:

- `@available(*, deprecated, message: "Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately.")`

Isn't passing for you. This could mean any of the following:

1. You set up your ML incorrectly
2. Your iOS isn't up to date

---

### **Easy Fix:**

All you have to do is paste this into your project:

```swift
extension SqueezeNet {
    convenience init(_ foo: Void) {
        try! self.init(contentsOf: type(of:self).urlOfModelInThisBundle)
    }
}
```

Then, edit your code like this:

```swift
guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: SqueezeNet(()).model) else { return }
```

It should no work fine. Please let me know if it doesn't.