# Using Core ML Audio Classification in Swift Playground

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I am trying to run the audio classification code from the 2019 WWTC presentation (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/425/) in an Xcode playground.

I modified the code and created an observer class (I think) but I get the error message »Argument type 'MyResultsObserver.Type' does not conform to expected type 'SNResultsObserving'« in line 40. Apparently there is something wrong with my class declaration but I don't know what.

Here is the code:

```
import SoundAnalysis
import PlaygroundSupport
import CoreML


class MyResultsObserver: NSObject, SNResultsObserving {
    func request(_ request: SNRequest, didProduce result: SNResult) {
        guard let classificationResult = result as? SNClassificationResult else { return }
        let topClassification = classificationResult.classifications.first
        let timeRange = classificationResult.timeRange
        // Handle result
    }
    func request(_ request: SNRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Handle error
    }
    
    func requestDidComplete(_ request: SNRequest) {
        
    }
    // Handle successful end of analysis
}


//Create a file analyzer
let fileAnalyzer = try SNAudioFileAnalyzer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Ben/Documents/SoundFile Classifier.playground/Resources/test.m4a"))


//Create the request with your MLModel
let request = try SNClassifySoundRequest(mlModel: Beep().model)

//Add the request to the analyzer
try fileAnalyzer.add(request, withObserver: MyResultsObserver)

//Analize the file
fileAnalyzer.analyze()
```

I have the »Beep.swift« file in my sources and »Beep.mlmodelc« in my resources.

The other thing that confuses me is that I get a »'init()' is deprecated: Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately.« warning in line 32. What is the correct initialization for SNClassifySoundRequest?

I hope that all makes sense an I am super grateful if anybody takes the time to have a look at my problem.

Cheers from Berlin

Comment: Try replacing `MyResultsObserver` with `MyResultsObserver()` (make sure to initialize the class)

Comment: For the other error, check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648967/a-warning-init-is-deprecated-swift-ios-app-learning-model

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll dig into that…

Comment: And how do I get timeRange and topClassification from the observer? Sorry for my lack of knowledge.